Compilation error : "Couldn't find header file: l3backend-dvips.pro"
Since I updated my TexLive Distribution, i get this error message when i compile with dvips :
/usr/local/bin/dvips: ! Couldn't find header file: l3backend-dvips.pro

The command kpsewhich -a l3backend-dvips.pro doesn't give any output even though the package l3backend is correctly installed.

This should now be fixed in TeX Live - it may take a while for all mirrors to update.

This was reported yesterday: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1548. An upload has been made to CTAN to address it, which may then take a day or two for propagation in TeX Live. You may wish to download the pre-extracted zip file from CTAN containing the required file and use it 'locally' until then.
