After the last tex update, the following document does not compile with latexmk. It issues the information Command for 'dvips' gave return code 256
This is the code of the document
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=35pt,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
%\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[expert,uprightgreek,altbullet]{lucidabr}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\everymath={\rm}
\def\TO{\quad$\rightarrow$\quad}

\graphicspath{ {./img/} }

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\today
\vspace{1.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=3.8em,yunit=2em] 
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {SC}
: {} {C'}
: {$C_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [+Q,-qu]$}}$} [scaleby=1.4]{ST}
:[scaleby=1.3]{SN$\mskip-5mu _m$}(<vartri>{La muchacha}) [scaleby=1.3]{T'}
: {T}  {SV} 
:{h$\mskip-5mu _m$} {V'}
: {V'}(<vert>{V}({bailó})) {SP}
<vert>{P'}
: {P}({con}) {SN}
: {D}({el}) {N'}(<vert>{N}({muchacho})) .
\endjtree

\jtree[xunit=3.8em,yunit=2em] 
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {SC}
: {} {C'}
: {$C_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [+Q,-qu]$}}$} [scaleby=1.4]{ST}
:[scaleby=1.3]{SN$\mskip-5mu _m$}(<vartri>{La muchacha}) [scaleby=1.3]{T'}
: !b  {SV} 
:{h$\mskip-5mu _m$} {V'}
: !a {SP}
<vert>{P'}
: {P}({con}) {SN}
 : {D}({el}) {N'}(<vert>{N}({muchacho})) .
\!a = {V'}
<vert>{$h_i$}@A2  .
\psset{scaleby=.4 .5}
 \!b = {T}
 : {\Vi}({bailó}@B2 )  {T} .
\nccurve[angleB=180,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B2}{A2}
\endjtree

\jtree[xunit=3.8em,yunit=2em] 
\def\Tj{T$\mskip-5mu _j$}
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {SC}
: {} {C'}
: [scaleby=1.4]!b [scaleby=1.4]{ST}
:[scaleby=1.3]{SN$\mskip-5mu _m$}(<vartri>{La muchacha}) [scaleby=1.3]{T'}
: {$h_j$}@B2 {SV} 
:{h$\mskip-5mu _m$} {V'}
: !a {SP}
<vert>{P'}
: {P}({con}) {SN}
 : {D}({el}) {N'}(<vert>{N}({muchacho})) .
\!a = {V'}
<vert>{$h_i$}@A2  .
\psset{scaleby=.4 .5}
\!b = {$C_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [+Q,-qu]$}}$}
: !c {$C_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [+Q,-qu]$}}$} .
 \!c = {\Tj}@A1
 : {\Vi}({bailó})  {T} .
\nccurve[angleB=180,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B2}{A2}
\nccurve[angleB=210,nodesepB=.5ex,angleA=180,ncurv=1.8]{<-}{A1}{B2} 
\endjtree

\jtree[xunit=3.8em,yunit=2em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {SN}
: {D}({el}) {N'}
:[scaleby=1.3]{N'}(<vert>{N}({muchacho})) [scaleby=1.3]{SC}
: !d {C'}
: {$C_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [-Q,+qu]$}}$} [scaleby=1.4]{ST}
:[scaleby=1.3]{SN$\mskip-5mu _m$}(<vartri>{la muchacha}) [scaleby=1.3]{T'}
:  !b {SV} 
:{h$\mskip-5mu _m$} {V'}
: !a {h$\mskip-5mu _k$}@B3 .
\!a = {V'}
<vert>{$h_i$}@A2  .
\psset{scaleby=.4 .5}
  \!b = {T}
 : {\Vi}({bailó}@B2 )  {T} .
 \!d = {SP$\mskip-5mu _k$}\\{$\scriptstyle [+qu]$}@A3
<vert>{P'}
: {P}({con}) {SN}(<vert>{N'}(<vert>{N}(({quien}\\{$\scriptstyle [+qu]$})))) .
\nccurve[angleB=180,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B2}{A2}
\nccurve[angleA=-150,angleB=-90,ncurv=1.3]{<-}{A3}{B3}
\endjtree

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {CP}
: {DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [\checkmark WH,\checkmark ACC]$}}$}(<vartri>{who}@F1 ) [scaleby=1.5]{C'}
:{C$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [\checkmark Q,\checkmark WH]$}}$}({do}@B1 ) {TP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [\checkmark NOM]$}}$}(<vartri>{you}@C1 ) {T'}
:{T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [NOM]$}}$}({$\scriptstyle PRES$}\\{\xout{do}}@A1 ) {VP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [+NOM]$}}$}(<vartri>{\xout{you}}@D1 ) {V'}
:{V}({think}) {CP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [+WH,\checkmark ACC]$}}$}(<vartri>{\xout{who}}@F ) [scaleby=1.5]{C'}
:{C$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [-Q,-WH]$}}$} {TP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [\checkmark NOM]$}}$}(<vartri>{Jim}@C ) {T'}
:{T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [NOM]$}}$}({-ed}@A ) {VP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [+NOM]$}}$}(<vartri>{\xout{Jim}}@D ) {V'}
:{V$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [+ACC]$}}$}({kiss+ed}@B ) {DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [+WH,\checkmark ACC]$}}$}(<vartri>{who}@E ). 
\nccurve[angleA=-90,angleB=180,ncurv=1.1]{->}{A}{B}
\ncput*[nrot=:U]{\scriptsize Affix Lowering}
\nccurve[angleB=210,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{C}{D}
\ncput*[nrot=:U]{\scriptsize DP-movement}
\nccurve[angleB=210,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{F}{E}
\ncput*[nrot=:U]{\scriptsize WH-movement}
\nccurve[angleB=210,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{F1}{F}
\ncput*[nrot=:U]{\scriptsize WH-movement}   
\nccurve[angleB=180,nodesepB=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1.1]{<-}{B1}{A1}
\ncput*[nrot=:U]{\scriptsize T$\rightarrow$C}
\nccurve[angleB=210,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{C1}{D1}
\ncput*[nrot=:U]{\scriptsize DP-movement}
\endjtree

$\begin{matrix}
creer,& V,&\hbox to 4em{(\thinspace \leaders\hrule\hfil } &  SC)\\
&  &  & [+QU]
\end{matrix}$

creer, V,\vtop{\hbox to 4em{(\thinspace \leaders\hrule\hfil\ NP)}%
\hbox to 4em{\hfil\ [+QU)}}


creer, V,\vtop{\hbox to 4em{(\thinspace \leaders\hrule\hfil\ NP)}%
\hbox to 4em{\hfil\ [+QU)}}\\



\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {ST}
:[scaleby=1.5]{SN}(<vartri>{él}) [scaleby=1.5]{T'}
: [scaleby=1.5]!b [scaleby=1.5]{ST$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle perf$}}$}
<vert>{T'$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle perf$}}$}
: [scaleby=1.5]!d [scaleby=1.5]{SV}
<vert>{V'}
:{$h_i$}@A1  {SN}\\{$\scriptstyle [fem]$}\\{$\scriptstyle [pl]$}(<vartri>{esas cosas}@A2 ) .
\psset{scaleby=.8 .9}
\!d = {T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle perf$}}$}
: !c {Conc}\\({$\scriptstyle [fem]$}\\{$\scriptstyle [pl]$}) .
\psset{scaleby=.4 .5}
 \!c = {T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle perf$}}$}
: {\Vi}(({dichas}\\{$\scriptstyle [fem]$}\\{$\scriptstyle [pl]$}@B1 )) {T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle perf$}}$} .
\!b = {T}
: {T}({ovo}) {Conc}\\({$\scriptstyle [3sg]$}) .
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B1}{A1} 
\nccurve[angleB=-160,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1.3]{<-}{A2}{B1}
\ncput*[nrot=:D]{\scriptsize concordancia} 
\endjtree

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {ST}
:[scaleby=1.5]{SD$\mskip-5mu _k$}(<vartri>{la muchacha}\\{$\scriptstyle [NOM]$}@A2 ) [scaleby=1.5]{T'}
:!b [scaleby=1.5]{SV} 
:{h$\mskip-5mu _k$} {V'}
: {$h_i$}@A1  {SD}(<vartri>{el partido}\\{$\scriptstyle [ACU]$}@B2 ) .
\psset{scaleby=.4 .5}
\!b = {T}
: !c {Conc}\\({$\scriptstyle [3sg]$}) .
 \!c = {T}
: {\Vi}({vio}@B1 )  {T}\\({$\scriptstyle [pas]$}@B3 ) .
\def\fudge{.5}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B1}{A1}
\ncbar[angleA=-90,angleB=-90,armA=2em,armB=1em,linearc=.6ex,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=blue,linewidth=.25ex]{<-}{B2}{A1} 
\ncbar[angleA=-90,angleB=-90,armA=3em,armB=1em,linearc=.6ex,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red,linewidth=.25ex]{->}{B3}{A2} 
 \endjtree
 
 \jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\deftriangle<tri>(1.8)(1)(-1)
\! = {SC}
<tri>{\triline{Es importante\hfil}} ^<tri>[triratio=.95]{SC}
: {} {C'}
: {C}({$\emptyset$}\\{$\scriptstyle [-Q]$}) [scaleby=1.5]{ST}
:[scaleby=1.5]{SD$\mskip-5mu _k$}(<vartri>{Juan}\\{$\scriptstyle [NOM]$}@A2 ) [scaleby=1.5]{T'}
:{T}\\({$\scriptstyle [-finito]$}) {SV} 
:{h$\mskip-5mu _k$} {V'}
: {V}({ver}@A1 )  {SD}(<vartri>{el partido}\\{$\scriptstyle [ACU]$}@B2 ) .
\ncbar[angleA=-90,angleB=-90,armA=2em,armB=1em,linearc=.6ex,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=blue,linewidth=.25ex]{<-}{B2}{A1} 
 \endjtree

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\deftriangle<tri>(1.8)(1)(-1)
\! = {SC}
<tri>{\triline{Es importante\hfil}} ^<tri>[triratio=.95]{SC}
: {} {C'}
: {C}({$\emptyset$}\\{$\scriptstyle [-Q]$}) [scaleby=1.5]{ST}
:[scaleby=1.5]{SD$\mskip-5mu _k$}(<vartri>{\multiline Sujeto\cr tácito\endmultiline}) [scaleby=1.5]{T'}
:{T}\\({$\scriptstyle [-finito]$}) {SV} 
:{h$\mskip-5mu _k$} {V'}
: {V}({ver}@A1 )  {SD}(<vartri>{el partido}\\{$\scriptstyle [ACU]$}@B2 ) .
\ncbar[angleA=-90,angleB=-90,armA=2em,armB=1em,linearc=.6ex,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=blue,linewidth=.25ex]{<-}{B2}{A1} 
 \endjtree

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {ST}
:[scaleby=1.5]{SD$\mskip-5mu _k$}(<vartri>{la muchacha}\\{$\scriptstyle [NOM]$}@A2 ) [scaleby=1.5]{T'}
:!b [scaleby=1.5]{SV} 
:{h$\mskip-5mu _k$} {V'}
: {$h_i$}@A1  {ST}
:{SD}(<vartri>{la lluvia}\\{$\scriptstyle [ACU]$}@B2 ) [scaleby=1.5]{T'}
:{T}\\({$\scriptstyle [-finito]$}) {SV} 
<vert>{V'}(<vert>{V}({caer})) .
\psset{scaleby=.4 .5}
\!b = {T}
: !c {Conc}\\({$\scriptstyle [3sg]$}) .
 \!c = {T}
: {\Vi}({veía}@B1 )  {T}\\({$\scriptstyle [pas]$}@B3 ) .
\def\fudge{.5}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B1}{A1}
\ncbar[angleA=-90,angleB=-90,armA=2em,armB=1em,linearc=.6ex,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=blue,linewidth=.25ex]{<-}{B2}{A1} 
\ncbar[angleA=-90,angleB=-90,armA=3em,armB=1em,linearc=.6ex,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red,linewidth=.25ex]{->}{B3}{A2} 
 \endjtree
\\
Chomsky (1995) propone sustituir las etiquetas resultado de la proyección por la misma unidad léxica.\\


Ensamble($\alpha, \beta$) = \{$\gamma$, \{$\alpha$, $\beta$\}\} donde la etiqueta $\gamma$ = es o bien la etiqueta de $\alpha$ o la etiqueta de $\beta$.\\

\vspace{.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.2em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {$\gamma$}
: {$\alpha$} {$\beta$} .
 \endjtree
 
\vspace{.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.4em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {C}
: {C} {T}
:[scaleby=1.5]!a [scaleby=1.5]{T} 
: {T} {leerá}
:[scaleby=1.5]{\xout{la niña}} [scaleby=1.5]{leerá}
:{leerá} {el} 
:{el} {libro} .
\!a = {la}
:{la} {niña} .
 \endjtree

\vspace{.5cm}

Ensamble($\alpha, \beta$) =  \{$\alpha$, $\beta$\}\\
\jtree[xunit=2.2em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {}
: {$\alpha$} {$\beta$} .
 \endjtree
 
Algoritmo de etiquetado

\pex[*] La etiqueta del ensamble de ($\alpha, \beta$) es $\alpha$ si
\a  $\alpha$ selecciona $\beta$ como argumento, o
\a  $\alpha$ atrae a $\beta$ para el cotejo de rasgos en concordancia en la configuración especificador-núcleo.
\xe

\vspace{.5cm}

Exocentric sentence

\pex[*=\#]
\a $\{\langle\phi,\phi\rangle, \{SN, SV\} \}$
\a\jtree[xunit=2.2em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {$\langle\phi,\phi\rangle$}
: {SN} {SV} .
 \endjtree
\xe

\vspace{.5cm}
Hipótesis del sujeto interno
\vspace{.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1.2em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {SV}
:{SN}(<vartri>{el hombre}) [scaleby=1.5]{V'}
:{V}({limpió}) {SN}(<vartri>{la ventana}) . 
 \endjtree


\vspace{.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1.2em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {ST}
: {} {T'}
:{T} {SV}
:{SN}(<vartri>{el hombre}) [scaleby=1.5]{V'}
:{V}({limpió}) {SN}(<vartri>{la ventana}) . 
 \endjtree
 

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1.2em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {ST}
: {SN}(<vartri>{el hombre}@C ) [scaleby=1.5]{T'}
:{T} {SV}
:{SN}(<vartri>{el hombre}@D ) [scaleby=1.5]{V'}
:{V}({limpió}) {SN}(<vartri>{la ventana}) .
\nccurve[angleB=180,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{C}{D} 
 \endjtree

\vspace{.5cm}

\noindent Forma Lógica después de la conversión de huellas en variables. Creación del predicado mediante abstracción de la variable lambda-ligada.

\pex 
\a $\lambda_{1}$ [$_{T'}$ T [$_{SV}$ \textbf{el}$_{1}$ hombre limpió la ventana]]
\a  \textlbrackdbl$\lambda_{1}$  \textbf{el}$_{1}$ hombre limpió la ventana\textrbrackdbl$^{g}$ = {\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont$\lambda$x:hombre(x).limpiar(x,la ventana)}
\xe

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1.2em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {ST}
: {SN}(<vartri>{el hombre}) [scaleby=1.5]{T'} 
:  {$\lambda_{1}$} {T'}
:{T} {SV}
:{SN}(<vartri>{\textbf{el}$_{1}$ hombre} ) [scaleby=1.5]{V'}
:{V}({limpió}) {SN}(<vartri>{la ventana}) .
 \endjtree

 \jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {ST}
:[scaleby=1.5]{SN}(<vartri>{la muchacha}@C ) [scaleby=1.5]{T'}
: [scaleby=1.5]!b [scaleby=1.5]{SV} 
:{SN}(<vartri>{\xout{la muchacha}}@D ) [scaleby=1.5]{V'}
: !a {SP}
<vert>{P'}
: {P}({con}) {SN}
 : {D}({el}) {N'}(<vert>{N}({muchacho})) .
\!a = {V'}
<vert>{$h_i$}@A1  .
\psset{scaleby=.4 .5}
\!b = {T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [PPE]$}}$}
: !c {Conc}\\({$\scriptstyle [3sg]$}) .
 \!c = {T}
: {\Vi}({bailó}@B1 )  {T}\\({$\scriptstyle [pas]$}) .
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B1}{A1} 
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-90,ncurv=3]{<-}{C}{D}
 \endjtree


 \jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {ST}
:[scaleby=1.5]{SN$\mskip-5mu _k$}(<vartri>{la muchacha}) [scaleby=1.5]{T'}
: [scaleby=1.5]!b [scaleby=1.5]{SV} 
:{h$\mskip-5mu _k$} [scaleby=1.5]{V'}
: !a {SP}
<vert>{P'}
: {P}({con}) {SN}
 : {D}({el}) {N'}(<vert>{N}({muchacho})) .
\!a = {V'}
<vert>{$h_i$}@A1  .
\psset{scaleby=.4 .5}
\!b = {T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [\checkmark PPE]$}}$}
: !c {Conc}\\({$\scriptstyle [3sg]$}) .
 \!c = {T}
: {\Vi}({bailó}@B1 )  {T}\\({$\scriptstyle [pas]$}) .
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B1}{A1} 
 \endjtree



\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\! = {ST}
: [scaleby=1.5]{SN}(<vartri>{ella}@C ) [scaleby=1.5]{T'}
: [scaleby=1.5]!b [scaleby=1.5]{SV}
:{SN}(<vartri>{\xout{ella}}@D ) {V'}(<vert>{V}({caminaba}@A1 )) .
\psset{scaleby=.4 .5}
\!b = {T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [PPE]$}}$}
: ({T}\\{$\scriptstyle [pas]$}@B1 ) ({Conc}\\{$\scriptstyle [3sg]$}) .
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B1}{A1}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-90,ncurv=3]{<-}{C}{D} 
\endjtree

\vspace{5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\! = {ST}
: {}[scaleby=1.5]{T'}
: [scaleby=1.5]!b [scaleby=1.5]{SV}
:{SN}(<vartri>{ella}) {V'}(<vert>{V}({caminaba}@A1 )) .
\psset{scaleby=.4 .5}
\!b = {T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [PPE]$}}$}
: ({T}\\{$\scriptstyle [pas]$}@B1 ) ({Conc}\\{$\scriptstyle [3sg]$}) .
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B1}{A1}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-90,ncurv=3]{<-}{C}{D} 
\endjtree
\TO
\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\! = {ST}
: {SN$\mskip-5mu _k$}(<vartri>{ella}) {T'}
: !b [scaleby=1.5]{SV}
:{h$\mskip-5mu _k$} {V'}(<vert>{V}({caminaba}@A1 )) .
\psset{scaleby=.6 .5}
\!b = {T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [\checkmark PPE]$}}$}
: !c {Conc}\\({$\scriptstyle [3sg]$}) .
 \!c = {T}
: {\Vi}({caminaba}@B1 )  {T}\\({$\scriptstyle [pas]$}) .
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-90,ncurv=1]{<-}{B1}{A1}  
\endjtree









\vspace{1.5cm}



\jtree[xunit=2.45em,yunit=1.4em,dirA=(1:-1),nodesep=0]
\def\\{[labelgapb=-4pt]}%
\def\V{$\overline V$}%
\! = {S}
<wideleft>{S}!a ^<vert>{and} ^<wideright>{S}
:({NP}<shortvert>{Fred}) {\V}
:({V}\\{knows}) {NP
}<tri>{a man} ^<right>
<right>[scaleby=3.5 1,branch=\blank]{NP}@A3     !b ^{S}
:({NP}<shortvert>{who})     {\V}@A2     
<left>({V}\\{repairs}) .
\!a = :({NP}<shortvert>{John})  {\V}@A1         
<left>{V}\\{sells} .
\!b = <vartri>{washing machines} .
\nccurve[angleB=150,ncurvB=1.4]{A2:b}{A3:t}
\nccurve[angleB=135,ncurvA=.5,ncurvB=2.6]{A1:b}{A3:t}
\endjtree





\jtree
\! = @A1    
<right>
:{B}
:{C} {D}@A2 .
\nccurve[dirA=(-1:-1),angleB=200,ncurv=2]{A1}{A2:t}
\endjtree



\vspace{1.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! =  {PredP}
:{}@B {Pred'}
:{Pred}({está}) {AP}
:{DP}({pro}) {A'}
:{A}({[e]}@B1 ) {AP}
:{DP}(<vartri>{el salmón}@A ) [scaleby=1.5]{A'}
:{A}({}@C )  {$\sqrt{\textsc{root}}$}({sabroso}@B2 ). 
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex,angleA=180,ncurv=1,linecolor=blue]{->}{A}{B}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{blue}\scriptsize DP-movement}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-145,ncurv=1.5,linecolor=red]{->}{C}{B1}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{red}\scriptsize A$\rightarrow$A}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-45,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{<-}{C}{B2}
\ncput*[nrot=:0]{\color{red}\scriptsize root$\rightarrow$A}
\endjtree

\vspace{1.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! =  {PredP}
:{}@B {Pred'}
:{Pred}({está}) [scaleby=1.5]{<AP,PredP>}
: !a  [scaleby=1.5]{PredP}(<vartri>{borracho}) .
\!a = {AP}
: {DP}({pro}) {A'}
:{A}({[e]}@B1 ) {AP}
:{DP}(<vartri>{el salmón}@A ) [scaleby=1.5]{A'}
:{A}({}@C )  {$\sqrt{\textsc{root}}$}({sabroso}@B2 ) . 
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex,angleA=180,ncurv=1,linecolor=blue]{->}{A}{B}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{blue}\scriptsize DP-movement}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-145,ncurv=1.5,linecolor=red]{->}{C}{B1}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{red}\scriptsize A$\rightarrow$A}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-45,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{<-}{C}{B2}
\ncput*[nrot=:0]{\color{red}\scriptsize root$\rightarrow$A}
\endjtree


\vspace{1.5cm}


\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em]
\def\broken{[branch=\brokenbranch,scaleby=1.6]}%\@1 
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {saP}
:{Speaker}@D [scaleby=1.5]{\omit}
:{sa} [scaleby=1.5]() \broken{ForceP}
:{ojalá}@A1 {\omit}
:{{$Force_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [EX]$}}$} }() \broken{MoodP}
:{\xout{ojalá}}\\({$\scriptstyle [i-mood]$}@B1 ) [scaleby=1.5] {\omit}
:{Mood}\\({$\scriptstyle [u-mood]$}) {FinP}
:{Fin}({$\emptyset$}) {TP}
: {PRO}@B {\omit} 
:{T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [\checkmark EPP]$}}$}  {AspP}
:{Asp}() \broken{vP} 
:  {\xout{PRO}}@C {\omit} 
:{v}  {VP}(<vartri>{ganar el premio}) .
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-145,ncurv=1,linecolor=blue]{->}{B1}{A1}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{blue}\scriptsize EX-movement}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-145,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{->}{C}{B}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{red}\scriptsize EPP-movement}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-145,ncurv=1]{<-}{B}{D}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\scriptsize Speaker-oriented Control}
\endjtree


\vspace{1.5cm}


\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em]
\def\broken{[branch=\brokenbranch,scaleby=1.8]}%\@1 
\def\Vi{V$\mskip-5mu _i$}
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {Sah}
:{Emisor}@D [scaleby=1.5]{\omit}
:{ah} [scaleby=1.5]() \broken{SFuerza}
:{ojalá}@A1 [scaleby=1.5]{\omit}
:{{$Fuerza_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [EX]$}}$} }() \broken{SModo}
:{\xout{ojalá}}\\({$\scriptstyle [i-modo]$}@B1 ) [scaleby=1.5] {\omit}
:{Modo}\\({$\scriptstyle [u-modo]$}) {SFin}
:{Fin}({$\emptyset$}) {ST}
: {PRO}@B {\omit} 
:{T$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle [\checkmark PPE]$}}$}  {SAsp}
:{Asp} {S\it v} 
:  {\xout{PRO}}@C {\omit} 
:{\it v}  {SV}(<vartri>{ganar el premio}) .
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-145,ncurv=1,linecolor=blue]{->}{B1}{A1}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{blue}\scriptsize movimiento-EX}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-145,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{->}{C}{B}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{red}\scriptsize movimiento-PPE}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex, nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-145,ncurv=1]{<-}{B}{D}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\scriptsize Control orientado al emisor}
\rput[bl](14ex,-7.4ex){(STop)}
\rput[bl](31.5ex,-16.5ex){(STop)}
\endjtree


\vspace{1.5cm}


\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! =  {PredP}
:{}@B {Pred'}
:{Pred}({está}) [scaleby=1.5]{<AP,PP>}
: [scaleby=1.5]!a  [scaleby=1.5]{PP}(<vartri>{\textbf{for} stimulus$($PRO$\mskip-1mu _i$$)$}) .
\!a = {AP}
: {DP}({pro$\mskip-1mu _i$}) {A'}
:{A}({[e]}@B1 ) {AP}
:{DP}(<vartri>{la comida}@A ) [scaleby=1.5]{A'}
:{A}({}@C )  {$\sqrt{\textsc{root}}$}({sabrosa}@B2 ) . 
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex,angleA=180,ncurv=1,linecolor=blue]{->}{A}{B}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{blue}\scriptsize DP-movement}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-145,ncurv=1.5,linecolor=red]{->}{C}{B1}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{red}\scriptsize A$\rightarrow$A}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-45,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{<-}{C}{B2}
\ncput*[nrot=:0]{\color{red}\scriptsize root$\rightarrow$A}
\endjtree

\vspace{1.5cm}


\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! =  {PredP}
:{}@B {Pred'}
:{Pred}({está}) [scaleby=1.5]{<AP,PP>}
: [scaleby=1.5]!a  [scaleby=1.6]{PP}(<vartri>[triratio=.3]{{\footnotesize \textbf{for} stimulus-experience$(s,$PRO$\mskip-1mu _i$$)$}}) .
\!a = {AP}
: [scaleby=1.5]{PP}({para María$\mskip-1mu _i$}) {A'}
:{A}({[e]}@B1 ) {AP}
:{DP}(<vartri>{la comida}@A ) [scaleby=1.5]{A'}
:{A}({}@C )  {$\sqrt{\textsc{root}}$}({sabrosa}@B2 ) . 
\nccurve[angleB=-135,nodesepB=.5ex,angleA=180,ncurv=1,linecolor=blue]{->}{A}{B}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{blue}\scriptsize DP-movement}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-145,ncurv=1.5,linecolor=red]{->}{C}{B1}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{red}\scriptsize A$\rightarrow$A}
\nccurve[angleB=-135,angleA=-45,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{<-}{C}{B2}
\ncput*[nrot=:0]{\color{red}\scriptsize root$\rightarrow$A}
\endjtree


\vspace{1.5cm}


\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! =  {PredP}
:{} {Pred'}
:{Pred} {AP}
: {DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$}  {A'}
:{A}({[e]}) {AP}
: {DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  SUBJ$}}$} {A'}
:{A}  {$\sqrt{\textsc{root}}$}  . 
\endjtree

\vspace{1.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {CopP}  
: {} {Cop'}
 :{Cop}({\multiline ser\cr estar\endmultiline}) [scaleby=1.5]{PredP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  SUBJ$}}$} {Pred'}
:{Pred}@B4  {DegP}
<vert> {Deg'}
:[scaleby=2]!a [scaleby=2]{PP}(<vartri>[triratio=.15]{\multiline \footnotesize $\lambda$c.c = typical counterpart of a at w,i\cr\footnotesize $\lambda$y.P(y)\hfill  \endmultiline}) .
\!a = {Deg'} 
:{Deg}({POS}@B3 )   {AP}
:{A}@B2  {$\sqrt{\textsc{root}}$}@B1  . 
\nccurve[angleB=180,nodesepB=.5ex,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=180,linecolor=red]{->}{B3}{B4}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-135,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{->}{B2}{B3}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-90,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{->}{B1}{B2}
\endjtree

\vspace{1.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {CopP}  
: {} {Cop'}
 :{Cop}({estar}) [scaleby=1.5]{PredP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  S/M$}}$} (<vartri>{el pulpo})[scaleby=1.5]{Pred'}
:{Pred}@B4  {DegP}
<vert> {Deg'}
:[scaleby=2]!a [scaleby=2]{PP}(<vartri>[triratio=.3]{{\footnotesize $\lambda$c.c = typical counterpart of pro$_{EXP}$ at w,i}}) .
\!a = {Deg'} 
:{Deg}({POS}@B3 )   {AP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$}({pro$\mskip-1mu _j$}) {A'}
:{A}@B2  {$\sqrt{\textsc{sabroso}}$}@B1  . 
\nccurve[angleB=-135,nodesepB=.5ex,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=180,linecolor=red]{->}{B3}{B4}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-135,ncurv=1.2,linecolor=red]{->}{B2}{B3}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-90,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{->}{B1}{B2}
\endjtree

\vspace{1.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {CopP}  
: {} {Cop'}
 :{Cop}({estar}) [scaleby=1.5]{PredP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  S/M$}}$} (<vartri>{el pulpo})[scaleby=1.5]{Pred'}
:{Pred}@B4  {DegP}
<vert> {Deg'}
:[scaleby=2]!a [scaleby=2]{PP}(<vartri>[triratio=.3]{{\footnotesize $\lambda$c.c = typical counterpart of Melania at w,i}}) .
\!a = {Deg'} 
:{Deg}({POS}@B3 )  {AP}
:{KP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$}({para Melania}) [scaleby=1.5]{A'}
:{A}@B2  {$\sqrt{\textsc{sabroso}}$}@B1  . 
\nccurve[angleB=-135,nodesepB=.5ex,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=180,linecolor=red]{->}{B3}{B4}
\nccurve[angleB=-135,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-135,ncurv=1.2,linecolor=red]{->}{B2}{B3}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-90,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{->}{B1}{B2}
\endjtree

\vspace{1.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {CopP}  
: {} {Cop'}
 :{Cop}({estar}) [scaleby=1.5]{PredP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  S/M$}}$} (<vartri>{el incendio})[scaleby=1.5]{Pred'}
:{Pred}@B4  {DegP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$} ({pro$\mskip-1mu _j$}) [scaleby=1.5]{Deg'}
:[scaleby=2]!a [scaleby=2]{PP}(<vartri>[triratio=.3]{{\footnotesize $\lambda$c.c = typical counterpart of pro$_{EXP}$ at w,i}}) .
\!a = {Deg'} 
:{Deg}({SUP}@B3 )  {AP}
:{A}@B2  {$\sqrt{\textsc{horrible}}$}@B1  . 
\nccurve[angleB=-135,nodesepB=.5ex,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=180,linecolor=red]{->}{B3}{B4}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-135,ncurv=1.2,linecolor=red]{->}{B2}{B3}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-90,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{->}{B1}{B2}
\endjtree

\vspace{1.5cm}


\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {CopP}  
: {} {Cop'}
 :{Cop}({estar}) [scaleby=1.5]{PredP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  S/M$}}$} (<vartri>{el incendio})[scaleby=1.5]{Pred'}
:{Pred}@B4  {DegP}
:{KP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$}({para Melania}) [scaleby=1.5]{Deg'}
:[scaleby=2]!a [scaleby=2]{PP}(<vartri>[triratio=.3]{{\footnotesize $\lambda$c.c = typical counterpart of Melania at w,i}}) .
\!a = {Deg'} 
:{Deg}({SUP}@B3 )  {AP}
:{A}@B2  {$\sqrt{\textsc{horrible}}$}@B1  . 
\nccurve[angleB=-135,nodesepB=.5ex,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=180,linecolor=red]{->}{B3}{B4}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-135,ncurv=1.2,linecolor=red]{->}{B2}{B3}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-90,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{->}{B1}{B2}
\endjtree

\vspace{1.5cm}

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! = {CopP}  
: {} {Cop'}
 :{Cop}({estar}) [scaleby=1.5]{PredP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  S/M$}}$} (<vartri>{el cuadro})[scaleby=1.5]{Pred'}
:{Pred}@B4  {DegP}
<vert> {Deg'}
:[scaleby=2]!a [scaleby=2]{PP}(<vartri>[triratio=.3]{{\footnotesize $\lambda$c.c = typical counterpart of pro$_{EXP}$ at w,i}}) .
\!a = {Deg'} 
:{Deg}({POS}@B3 )   {AP}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$}({pro$\mskip-1mu _j$}) {A'}
:{A}@B2  {$\sqrt{\textsc{bello}}$}@B1  . 
\nccurve[angleB=-135,nodesepB=.5ex,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=180,linecolor=red]{->}{B3}{B4}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepA=.5ex,angleA=-135,ncurv=1.2,linecolor=red]{->}{B2}{B3}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-90,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{->}{B1}{B2}
\endjtree

\vspace{1.5cm}



\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\! = {AP}
: [scaleby=1.5]{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$}({pro$_{\phi}$}({\multiline $\scriptstyle\rm [se]\hfill$\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [+generic]$\hfill\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [-feminine]$\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [-plural]$\hfill\endmultiline}) ) [scaleby=1.5]{\omit} 
:{A}()  \etc .
\endjtree

\vspace{1.5cm}


\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\! = {AP}
: [scaleby=1.5]!a  [scaleby=1.5]{\omit} 
:{A}()  \etc .
\!a = {<DP, SP>}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$}({pro$_{\phi}$}({\multiline $\scriptstyle\rm [se]\hfill$\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [+generic]$\hfill\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [-feminine]$\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [-plural]$\hfill\endmultiline}) ) {SP}(<vartri>{borracho}) .
\endjtree

\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%\@1
\! = {AP}
: [scaleby=1.5]{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$}({x}({\multiline $\scriptstyle\rm \lambda x.\mathbf{author}(x)$\cr$\scriptstyle\rm x\,qua\, \lambda y.\mathbf{Sim}(\mathbf{borracho}(y))$\endmultiline}) ) [scaleby=1.5]{\omit} 
:{A}()  \etc .
\endjtree



\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! =  {PredP}
:[scaleby=1.5]{}@B [scaleby=1.5]{Pred'}
:{Pred}({está}) [scaleby=1.5]{AP}
: [scaleby=1.5]{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$}({pro$_{\phi}$}({\multiline $\scriptstyle\rm [se]\hfill$\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [+generic]$\hfill\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [-feminine]$\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [-plural]$\hfill\endmultiline}) )[scaleby=1.5]{A'}
:{A}({[e]}@B1 ) {AP}
:{DP}(<vartri>{el salmón}@A ) [scaleby=1.5]{A'}
:{A}({}@C )  {$\sqrt{\textsc{root}}$}({sabroso}@B2 ). 
\nccurve[angleB=-90,nodesepB=.5ex,angleA=-145,ncurv=1,linecolor=blue]{->}{A}{B}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{blue}\scriptsize DP-movement}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-145,ncurv=1.5,linecolor=red]{->}{C}{B1}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{red}\scriptsize A$\rightarrow$A}
\nccurve[angleB=-90,angleA=-45,ncurv=1,linecolor=red]{<-}{C}{B2}
\ncput*[nrot=:0]{\color{red}\scriptsize root$\rightarrow$A}
\endjtree


\jtree[xunit=2.8em,yunit=1em] 
\def\\{[labelgapb=-1.2ex]}%
\! =  {PredP}
:[scaleby=1.5]{}@B [scaleby=1.5]{Pred'}
:{Pred}({está}) [scaleby=1.5]{AP}
: [scaleby=1.5]!a [scaleby=1.75]{A'}
:{A}({[e]}@B1 )[scaleby=1.5]{AP}
:{DP}(<vartri>{el salmón}@A ) [scaleby=1.5]{A'}
:{A}({}@C )  {$\sqrt{\textsc{root}}$}({sabroso}@B2 ) .
\!a = {<DP, SP>}
:{DP$_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle  EXP$}}$}({pro$_{\phi}$}({\multiline $\scriptstyle\rm [se]\hfill$\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [+generic]$\hfill\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [-feminine]$\cr$\scriptstyle\rm [-plural]$\hfill\endmultiline}) ) {SP}(<vartri>{borracho}) . 
\ncbar[angle=-90,arrows=->,nodesep=0pt,linearc=.8ex,labelsep=.25ex,armA=4.5ex,offsetB=.25ex,linecolor=blue]{A}{B}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{blue}\scriptsize DP-movement}
\ncangle[angleA=180,angleB=-90,arrows=->,nodesepB=.5ex,nodesepA=4pt,linearc=.7ex,labelsep=.25ex,armA=2.5ex,offsetB=.25ex,linecolor=red]{->}{C}{B1}
\ncput*[nrot=:180]{\color{red}\scriptsize A$\rightarrow$A}
\ncbar[angle=-90,arrows=->,nodesep=0pt,linearc=.7ex,labelsep=.25ex,armA=2.5ex,offsetB=.25ex,linecolor=red]{<-}{C}{B2}
\ncput*[nrot=:0]{\color{red}\scriptsize root$\rightarrow$A}
\endjtree









\end{document}

The document compiles ok with latexmk -pdflua. I know is a font problem, but I haven't the slighest idea of what is going wrong after the update. My updmap.cfg file in the my user directory is the following. Since I haven't run updmap-user in a long time I didn't know that this font was missing. Does it have something to do with the compilation problem? Sorry for the long post, but I am kind of desperate. Thanks to the latex community out there.
Map lucida.map


#! Map ${PKGNAME}.map
Map lumath-k.map


Looks like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/718745/compilation-error-couldnt-find-header-file-l3backend-dvips-pro/718746#718746 to me

Wow. Indeed. Thank you very much.

@JosephWright I wish it would warn me when it's going to close a question like that and I wouldn't do it.

You also can compile this document with lualatex to get directly a PDF. Then you do not need the type1 versions of the font but can use the oprn type versions.

Thank you, @user187802. Yes, I know, I normally use a copy of this document that I run with lualatex, but I keep this document with the type1 versions to ensure compatibility of my texlive enviroment with potential updates.
